# Post user name and pass it automatically in website (travian) and login

Tags: c#, authentication

This is login page: http://ts14.travian.com.sa/nachrichten.php

I want the program to post the username and pass word form a text box and my simple poor browser:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://ts14.travian.com.sa");
            textBox1.Text = "متصفح خاص بترافيان";
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.GoBack();
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.GoForward();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate(label1.Text);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Refresh();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://ts14.travian.com.sa/logout.php");
        }

        private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate(textBox2.Text);

        }

        private void closeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void tabPage2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

What do I have to do to make the browser login to the game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thx  man i found a way to do it by detect the HtmlelementId then change its value
like this

{

```
                 HtmlElement ele = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("usernameID"); if (ele != null)
            ele.InnerText = "username"; 

        ele = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("passwordID"); if (ele != null)
            ele.InnerText = "password";

        ele = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("goButtonID"); if (ele != null)
            ele.InvokeMember("click");
```

}
it worked ok

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a POST HTTP request to http://ts14.travian.com.sa/dorf1.php passing the form variables required. You need to understand how they process the login request. You can try something like this:

```
            StreamWriter Sw = null;
            StreamReader Sr = null;
            string sUsername = "aUsername";
            string sPassword = "aValidPass";

            string data = string.Format("name={0}&password={1}", sUsername, sPassword);

            HttpWebRequest Req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://ts14.travian.com.sa/dorf1.php");
            Req.Method = "POST";
            Req.KeepAlive = true;

            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] byte1 = encoding.GetBytes(data);
            Req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            Req.ContentLength = byte1.Length;
            Stream newStream = Req.GetRequestStream();
            newStream.Write(byte1, 0, byte1.Length);
            newStream.Close();

            Sr = new StreamReader(((HttpWebResponse)Req.GetResponse()).GetResponseStream());
            sResponse = Sr.ReadToEnd();
            int cookieCount = cookieJar.Count;
            Sr.Close();
            Sw = null;
```

Once you get a success login (parsing the variable sResponse) you can just redirect to the page.

BUT REMEMBER.... your session will live only within the machine where the application is running.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a POST HTTP request to http://www.weedi.net/vb/f-127/29251/ passing the form variables required. You need to understand how they process the login request. You can try something like this:

```
 StreamWriter Sw = null;
        StreamReader Sr = null;
        string sUsername = "aUsername";
        string sPassword = "aValidPass";

        string data = string.Format("name={0}&password={1}", sUsername, sPassword);

        HttpWebRequest Req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://ts14.travian.com.sa/dorf1.php");
        Req.Method = "POST";
        Req.KeepAlive = true;



                                                                    .
```

Comment: the code supplied is a little confusing, you've got unused variables in there and don't actually show how to initiate the request to the server